# Fatal lint error when attempting to sign app

Tags: android, fatal-error, lint

When I attempt to sign my app so that I can create a keystore to get the Google Maps API key, I get this error.

```
"so and so" is not translated in bg, ca, cs, de, es, fi, fr, id, it, iw, ja, ko, lt, lv, nl, no, pl, pt, pt-rBR, ru, 
 sv, vi, yr, zh-rCN, zh-rTW
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Yes; translate that text or don't use those languages.

Comment: how do I not use those languages? All I want is english.